# How to use Console.ReadKey() while avoiding the same key being registered constantly after, C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, controls

I would like to make a program which will let the user decide what program to run, by pressing certain keys. I have now come so far that some of these keys work perfectly. However I have now come to a problem that I have a difficult time to solve. Now when I press a key it activates the same thing that was activated before even though I press a different key. I believe that the issue lies in the WaitForKey()-method, but I am not sure where in there. Can you help me to locate the issue and bring in some solutions to this?

note: hasBeenPressed is a Boolean value which tells if the key has already been pressed or not and if so it should avoid activating some other functionality automatically.

```
public static void WaitForKey(ConsoleKey key) {
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (keyInfo.Key == key && hasBeenPressed == false) {
        hasBeenPressed = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (keyInfo.Key == key) {
        hasBeenPressed = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

I use the WaitForKey() in this context:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mySignalChain.Count - 1; i++) {
   if (keyPress.Key == ConsoleKey.I) {                       
       pedalsActivated(mySignalChain)           
       WaitForKey(ConsoleKey.I);
   }
```

I hope this was clear otherwise I will try to elaborate on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that you are always checking against ConsoleKey.I (letter I, code 73), so the program will not respond to other keys. In the line if (keyPress.Key == ConsoleKey.I)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that this is the problem. I just don't understand why it does not update the keyPress.Key when another key is pressed. Do you have any suggestion what I can do to let the keyPress.Key be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of what you would like to achieve,

> I would like to make a program which will let the user decide what program to run, by pressing certain keys.

I wrote the following Console Application that will execute a different function depending on the key you press (I, J, or K), and will keep asking for keys until the user presses a different key, in which case the program will finish.

```
var exit = false;

ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a new Key");

    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine();

    switch (keyInfo.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.I:
            FunctionFor_I();
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.J:
            FunctionFor_J();
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.K:
            FunctionFor_K();
            break;

        default:
            ExitProgram();
            break;

    }
}

while (exit == false);

void FunctionFor_I()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I has been pressed");
}

void FunctionFor_J()
{
    Console.WriteLine("J has been pressed");
}

void FunctionFor_K()
{
    Console.WriteLine("K has been pressed");
}

void ExitProgram()
{
    exit = true;
}
```

I tried to replicate your code first and see how it works, but I couldn't understand its purpose so I focused on your textual description of the problem. If this is not what you intended, please post the full version of your code and I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like the suggestion of using switch statements instead however it spams the first key that I press after I have implemented the switch statements. And if I copy-paste your presented code it gives me a lot of compiler errors - for example the "while (exit == false);" and I have tried to work around it and work with the idea, but to no success. But I do think that you understand what I want. I only want the function to be run once after pressing a key and then go back to the switch statement.

Comment: Are you working with Visual Studio? What kind of project do you have, Console Application? And what is the framework? .NET Framework , .NET core, .NET?

Comment: No, I am working with Visual Studio Code with .Net. 

Target framework: .NET Core App version 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed my issue (somewhat) by doing the following:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);
while (keyPress.Key != ConsoleKey.Q) {
    switch (keyPress.Key) {
         case ConsoleKey.I:
             pedalsActivated(mySignalChain);
             Console.WriteLine("");
             WaitForKey(ConsoleKey.I);
             keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);
             break;
       .
       .
       .
}
```

By using my function WaitForKey() defined above I can now activate my functions while at the same time avoiding a certain key being spammed. But then I also reset the keyPress (by: keyPress = Console.Readkey(true);) so that other functions can be called with other keys - though I have to press every key twice now to do so. This works better than having to press the keys far more than twice - however it would be optimal if I would only need to press each key once. And if anyone has an idea how to do so it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the FULL code, if not it's very difficult to help you. For starters, the while loop lacks the enclosing character }. If you post the FULL code, even though it seems lengthy and verbose, it will be much easier to help you.